# How to write ASCII code on serial port in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ascii

I am trying to send ASCII code (for ENTER, SPACE, SHIFT, F1, F2, F3 and F4 keys) serially in Powershell

```
port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,115200,None,8,one
$port.open()

# Carriage return - ENTER 
$port.WriteLine("`r")
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
$port.ReadExisting()

[Byte[]] $request = 13
$port.Write($request)
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

$port.ReadExisting()

$port.Close()
```

Here in above code, I am sending Carriage Return serially. When I use `WriteLine` then it works but it fails when I am trying with `Write`.

Answer (score 1):

Often CR+LF work as a command terminator on serial ports, so it probably doesn't pick up what you are doing unless you WriteLine. To send a CR+LF you should try

```
$port.Write("`r`n")
```

Comment: Thanks. What about these keys (SPACE, SHIFT, F1, F2, F3 and F4 ) ?

Comment: Space should be trivial. The others aren't characters, they are keys/scan codes. That's something different. It's up to the receiving end how to encode those, so please check the documentation for whatever device you are communicating with.

Comment: My requirement is that I want to send keystrokes from Powershell script serially.

Comment: I understand your requirement, but you write characters on the the serial port, not scan codes, so there is no way to write F1. Your only hope is that the receiving end has some way to receive key presses, so again: Check the documentation.